# What is the browser support for neat?

Tags: bourbon, neat

Specifically, does Neat version 2 support IE?
Is it tested in IE/Edge etc?
What other browsers are supported or not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be absolutely fine - the only major feature Neat uses where there may be *some* support issues is `calc`. See this post in the issues:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/631

And information about browser support for `calc` here:

https://caniuse.com/#search=calc

I have tested in IE11 and Edge with no issues